# How to provision Sitecore 9.3 XP scaled in Azure as App Services only for CM and CD role using Azure tool kit

Tags: azure, installation, azure-toolkit

We have a requirement to provision a fresh installation of `Sitecore 9.3 XP scaled in Azure` using App Services only for `CM and CD roles`.

We don't need xDB and EXM as of now but maybe we will configure them in future.
In order to reduce costs, we want to keep only CM and CD roles and their required databases.

We used Azure tool kit for XP scaled but the tool kit provisioned all the available roles present in XP.

One way to do this is to configure it manually after the initial setup. Though it will be time and cost consuming.

Is there anything else we can do? We don't want to use XM scaled topology as we have an XP license and we may decide to use all other roles in future.

Can anyone advise how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you just use default scripts, create all the services and then remove those which you don't need?

Comment: Thanks. Yes this way we are doing as of now. But is there any other way to setup only CM and CD role and ignore other from setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is definately possible by modifying the configuration in the SIF scripts. There will be a bit of effort involved however so I'd probably just use the default scripts and remove what you don't need as Marek suggested.

The benefit of spinning it all up initially is that you could back up the DB's and Roles connection strings etc so that it's easier to bring back in later if you do decide to do so. If you don't do that, you'll end up having to 'frankenstien' stitch it all back together later.

If you really wanted to just spin up CM and CD alone, here's where you can get started. In the 9.3 XP Scaled installation folders configuration directory, the XP1-Distrubuted.json file - notice that this contains each of the Roles configurations to be run so you could try just including the roles you want. Depending on what you're doing you might want to strip out all of the other parameters and installation artefacts which you don't need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to provision the XM Scaled topology.  The Azure QuickStart templates for 9.3 XM are here:

https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%209.3.0/XM

This ARM template will setup the following resources: CM, CD, SI, SQL, Azure Search (if required) and AI.